# \include vs \usepackage

Tags: package-writing

I have some doubt about the correct approach to document modularity. Main main doubt is about the usage of custom packages in the creation of a *complex* structure document.
In my first `LaTeX` work I made a custom package (`.sty`) with structure / commands definitions and other global settings. This allowed me to fix several compilation issues I had placing everything in a single file but I soon noticed some negative drawbacks about such approach:

- the custom `.sty` package referenced trough `\usepackage` directive is not found/recognized by `TeXstudio` editor (altough it is correctly compiled by `LaTeX`).
- compilation errors in custom package are 'mitigated' and anyway is often difficult to find the correct reference to the error.
- the templates / sample files I read learning `LaTeX` did not use such approach but often use \inlcude \input directives.

This's my document structure:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,a5paper,twoside,openright,italian,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{defines}

\author{The Author}
\date{2016}
\title{The Title}
\editor{The Editor}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mytitle

\tableofcontents

\include{Preface}

\mainmatter

\include{Chapter01}

\include{Chapter02}

\end{document}
```

and this is my custom package (the name is `defines.sty`):

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc}

\newcommand{\editor}[1]{
    \def\@editor{#1}
}

\newcommand{\theeditor}{
    \@editor
}

\newcommand{\eachpageornament}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, color=LimeGreen]
        \transparent{0.75}{     
            \node[anchor=north west](CNW) at (current page.north west){
                \pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};
            \node[anchor=north east](CNE) at (current page.north east){
                \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
            \node[anchor=south west](CSW) at (current page.south west){
                \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
            \node[anchor=south east](CSE) at (current page.south east){
                \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
            \pgfornamenthline{CNW}{CNE}{north}{87}
            \pgfornamenthline{CSW}{CSE}{south}{87}
            \pgfornamentvline{CNW}{CSW}{west}{87}
            \pgfornamentvline{CNE}{CSE}{east}{87}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\plogo}{
    \includegraphics[width = 30mm]{logo.png}
}

\newcommand{\psignature}{
    \begin{flushright}
        \def\svgwidth{40mm}
        \input{signature.pdf_tex}
    \end{flushright}
}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \ThisCenterWallPaper{1.1}{sfondo}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        {\transparent{0.95}\node [rectangle, rounded corners, fill=LimeGreen, anchor=south west, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=8cm] (box) at (-0.5,-10) (box){};}
        \node[anchor=west, xshift=-2.0cm, yshift=-1cm, text width=4cm] at (box.north){\large \textit{\theeditor}}; 
        \node[anchor=west, xshift=-2.0cm, yshift=-3.5cm, text width=4cm] at (box.north){\huge \thetitle};
        \node[anchor=west, xshift=-2.0cm, yshift=-6cm, text width=4cm] at (box.north){\large \theauthor};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \newpage
}

\backgroundsetup{
    contents={
        \if@mainmatter 
            \eachpageornament \thepage
        \else
        \ifnum\value {page}=1 
        \else 
            \eachpageornament \thepage
        \fi
        \fi
    },
    position=current page.north east,
    angle=0,
    scale=1,
    opacity=1
}

\renewcommand{\poemtoc}{section}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\normalfont\large\itshape\centering} 

\pagestyle{plain}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

If I rename the package in `.tex` and include it (trough `\include` or `\input`) I got several errors.

I have another doubt about the use of `memoir` class instead `book` ... If I use the second instead the first one I got a number of errors regarding references to commands defined in the custom package.

Comment: If you load TeX code (extension `.sty`) via `\usepackage` then `@` will be treated as ordinary letter and can appear in macro names, which is used to defined internal macros that shouldn't be used by the user. If you load the same code (extension `.tex`) using `\input`, you will have to surround the `\input` statement by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. If you don't do it, you will get lots of errors and unusable code.

Comment: `\include` should not be abused for mere code loading

Comment: What do you mean by the ”`\usepackage` directive is not found/recognized by TeXstudio"? Secondly, in `.sty` files loaded with `\usepackage` commands with @ are automatically enabled, which doesn't happen with `\input`. Thirdly, you should  never use `\include` for loading macro definitions.

Comment: Regarding the difference between `\input` and `\include`, see [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/110998)

Comment: Of course you get errors when replacing the `memoir` class by `book`. Both define document classes for large documents, but the first one is an extension of the second one with many more options; see the [memoir documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf) for details. You cannot expect that the extensions still work when going back to `book`.

Comment: Maybe your problems have mainly to do with TeXstudio. TeX usually has no problems finding files, and in the log output it is also quite clear to which files the line numbers refer since the opening and closing of processed files is indicated. My feeling is that integrated TeX environments that hide what's going on underneath are for standard users. If you plan to handle complex documents distributed over many files, it is maybe better to switch to a LaTeX-sensitive editor and to work from the command line for complex things.

Comment: @egreg nope ... as I wrote the error is related to the referenced file not the `\usepackage` directive itselft .. in short it recognize `\usepackage` but it 's not *finding* the file... but this maybe it's just a problem of `TeXstudio` instead `LaTeX` itself.

Comment: @weirdgyn see the form in the comment where line breaks appear as spaces, that is also what tex does. `\newcommand\foo{ a }` is not the same as `\newcommand\foo{a}`  so if you do not want a space in the output do not add spaces or newlines at that position. (or if you do add linebreaks just to indent the source, you need to comment them out with `%`)

Comment: @weirdgyn I'd use `.sty` so as not having to bother with `\makeatletter`. But there's not really a big difference, except that `\usepackage{defines}` will not load again the file, even if issued more than once.

Comment: but your question is still not very clear, the title is `\include` v `\usepacakge` but there are no cases where there is a possibility of choosing between those two,. `\include` does not work before `\begin{document}` and `\usepackage` gives an error if used after `\begin{document}`

Comment: "literature"? I mean that in any latex document that there are no contexts where both `\include` and `\usepackage`  are reasonable commands to use at that point. The contexts where they may be used have no overlap.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok I got the point.. you meant that `\include` and `\usepackage` have different scopes .. correct.. that's literature (that's good). The `LaTeX` way prescribe different contexts where to apply such directives... my doubt can be resumed in this question: _"What's the correct way to do what I need to do? I have to use `\include` ? I have to use `\usepackage` .. I have to put everything in the same `.tex` file?"_

Comment: sorry I think unless you can clarify your question to actually have a question I think that closing as unclear is the only option (or as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/110998) it is not really answerable in its current form

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44194/discussion-on-question-by-weirdgyn-include-vs-usepackage).